# VBA display value from row 1 and so on

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Button1Click()

    Dim temp As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim Cancel As Boolean

    Cancel = False

    Set temp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

    Dim tempAct As String
    Dim tempCC As String
    Dim tempRan As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    tempAct = Range("B1").Value
    tempCC = Range("B2").Value
    tempRan = Range("B3").Value
    Set TEMP_TEMPLATE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")

    Set rng = temp.Range("B1:B3")
    For Each cell In rng
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            MsgBox ("Blank Input!")
            Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Cancel = False Then
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Range("C1").Value = tempAct
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Range("C2").Value = tempCC
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Range("C3").Value = tempRan
    End If

End Sub
```

This Post is continuing my last post. Bug fixed by jmstoker
This time I want to display the result not in C1, C2, C3
but lets say A1, B1, C1, 
and every time the user input again, it will display continuously A2, B2, C2  -  A3, B3, C3 and so on
any idea to replace this one?

**`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Range("C1").Value = tempAct`**

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working dynamic solution with minimum required read / write transactions: 
Copy-paste this into a workbook and play around with it.

What this code basically does is create a global object that contains the values that you want to display in the database sheet. 
When the workbook is opened, the object gets initialized; previous values are loaded from the database sheet into memory, and they stay in memory during the lifetime of the workbook. Unfortunately, VBA cannot remember the global object once you closed the workbook, which is why you are forced to read the data from a sheet. So you need to save the workbook before you close it or your data are lost (without this solution, that would of course be the case as well).

Every time you want to add a new row to the "database", the object's row counter gets updated and then the updated array is printed onto the worksheet in just one write transaction.

This code is just a prototype that you can use to play around. 
You'll find that this logic is applicable in many situations. 
The benefit is that you can very easily customize the code when you have new requirements and future developers may be grateful for that.

**Edit**
This is a typical question many Excel VBA developers struggle with, finding solutions to update a static worksheet. Be aware that if you choose for a static solution, bugs may occur when new columns are inserted or when blank rows mess things up. 
The best solution for Excel is to connect to an Access database, which is a very, very easy thing to do. In only a few lines of code, you can store any data you want. In case you plan to store more data, certainly consider this option.

1) Thisworkbook module

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call get_database
End Sub
```

2) Regular VBA module: "m_database"

```
Option Explicit
Global cDatabase As New c_database

Sub Upload_to_db()

cDatabase.setRow
cDatabase.TempAct = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1").Value
cDatabase.TempCc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a2").Value
cDatabase.TempRan = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a3").Value

cDatabase.write_to_database

End Sub

Function get_database()
    cDatabase.set_array
End Function
```

3) Class module: c_database

```
Option Explicit

Private pTempAct        As String
Private pTempCc         As String
Private pTempRan        As String

Private array_database() As Variant
Private pMax_row        As Long
Private pRow            As Long


Const tempAct_col = 1
Const tempCc_col = 2
Const tempRan_col = 3
Const nr_of_cols = 3

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pMax_row = 1000000
    ReDim array_database(1 To pMax_row, 1 To nr_of_cols)
End Sub

Public Property Let TempAct(sValue As String)

    pTempAct = sValue
    array_database(pRow, tempAct_col) = pTempAct

End Property

Public Property Let TempCc(sValue As String)

    pTempCc = sValue
    array_database(pRow, tempCc_col) = pTempCc

End Property

Public Property Let TempRan(sValue As String)

    pTempRan = sValue
    array_database(pRow, tempRan_col) = pTempRan

End Property

Public Function setRow()
    pRow = pRow + 1
End Function

Public Function write_to_database()

    Dim lNr_Rows            As Long
    Dim iNr_Cols            As Integer
    Dim oRange              As Excel.Range


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("database").Cells.Clear
    lNr_Rows = pRow
    iNr_Cols = nr_of_cols

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("database").Activate
    Set oRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("database").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lNr_Rows, iNr_Cols))
    oRange = array_database

End Function

Public Function set_array()

    Dim oRange              As Excel.Range
    Dim iRange_rows         As Integer
    Dim lCnt                As Long


    Set oRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("database").UsedRange
    iRange_rows = oRange.Rows.Count

    For lCnt = 1 To iRange_rows

        array_database(lCnt, tempAct_col) = oRange.Cells(lCnt, tempAct_col)
        array_database(lCnt, tempCc_col) = oRange.Cells(lCnt, tempCc_col)
        array_database(lCnt, tempRan_col) = oRange.Cells(lCnt, tempRan_col)

    Next lCnt

    pRow = oRange.Rows.Count

End Function
```

Comment: Ok. Note: in this case you can use UsedRange on the condition that you properly validate the values submitted to the database sheet. Since you clear the sheet every time you perform a write, there is no risk for values randomly floating around in the sheet. You could extend the class with a function that takes care of the validation for you as well.